# Родительный падеж множественного числа слова «воробей»

Tags: склонение, падежи, существительные

Родительный падеж множественного числа слова *воробей — воробь**ёв**.*
Не *воробеев*. Почему?
Есть же слова *прохиндей, ротозей, лицедей*.  В родительном падеже они оканчиваются на "-еев".

Comment: Ударение разное в словах этих — выбор пользователей языка, закрепленный в словаре.

Comment: Вопрос должен звучать так: откуда взялся **Ь**?

Comment: И тем не менее)

Comment: Я имею в виду не очевидные вещи, что мол произношение и написание закрепилось временем, а именно конкретное правило или скорее исключение из оных.

Comment: Здесь нет правила, это обычная грамматика, фонетика, графика: окончание ОВ/ЁВ/ЕВ в Р.п. , ЕВ— безударное окончание после мягкого согласного, а ЁВ — ударное. Правило — это выбор, а здесь что выбирать. Ударение определяет написание.

Comment: Правила и исключения есть для шипящих и Ц, а здесь обычные согласные, парные по мягкости/твердости.

Comment: То есть, если я вас правильно понял, есть куча примеров, где это применяется с существительными и мои примеры в шапке некорректны?

Comment: Я не нашел ни одного примера с окончанием "оробей" в русском языке, где бы мог опереться на подобное. Про корень "оро" я в курсе. Про окончание "ей", также. И кроме этого слова, нарицательных и прочих фамилий, я не встречал подобного а русском языке.

Comment: То есть, это не исключение, а ударение определяет написание. И больше опереться не на что. Есть так, как есть. Верно?

Comment: Да, именно так.  Иначе не напишешь. Пример из другой  темы, где есть выбор (беглые гласные Е/И): ружье/ружей, судья/судей, но копье – копий.  Правило:  
 ЕЙ В ОСНОВЕ: беглая гласная Е. Существительные женского и среднего рода на ЬЯ, ЬЁ в форме Р.п. множественного числа оканчиваются на ЕЙ (нулевое окончание), где Е – беглая гласная, если в начальной форме УДАРЕНИЕ ПАДАЕТ НА ОКОНЧАНИЕ: ружьё – ружей, судья – судей, полынья – полынЕй, но: копьё – копИЙ (исключение).

Comment: ИЙ В ОСНОВЕ: беглая гласная И.  Существительные среднего рода на ЬЕ в форме Р.п. множественного числа оканчиваются на ИЙ (нулевое окончание), где И – беглая гласная, если в начальной форме УДАРЕНИЕ ПАДАЕТ НА ОСНОВУ: поместье – поместий, гнездовье – гнездовий, снАдобье – снАдобий.

Comment: Спасибо! С новым годом!

Comment: И вас тоже. Заходите еще)

Answer (score 0):

вор+о+бей - один из корней бей, бить, бьёт - **Б'** - где ёТ-ИТЬ- - глагольный суффикс. Воро**бь**ёв. Хотя, есть фамилия Воробец.

лиц+е+дей - второй корень дей-дея, де+ят+ель, де+л+о, де+л+ить, де+ян+ие - **ДЕ**. Лице**де**ев - слов дьёт-дьит-дить не образуется, так как корень другой, хотя есть производные вроде корней РОД+ить, ХОД+ить, но в качественной форме Д будет превращаться в Ж - РОЖев, ПроХОЖев, ну либо это будет Высокородов, Скороходов:

> Высокородов Павел Илларионович **.**.1898 г. рождения.

> Скороходов, Валентин Николаевич (1911—1930) — советский учитель, борец за построение социализма.

> Прохожев Василий Анисимович. (1903,Саратовская обл.,д.Ильмень---1937)

мурав'+ей - корни мур(трава) или мурава-муравь - муравьи. **Муравь**ёв. Хотя, есть фамилия Мурав+ник.

рот+о+зей - зев+ать, зев+ак+а, зи+ять - **ЗЕ-ЗИ**. Рото**зе**ев.

мед+вед+ь - корень ВЕД. Мед**вед***ев*, а не Медвед*ьев*.